# Running a blocking request

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I read that Firebase runs its operations on background threads, and its callbacks on the UI thread.

Is there a way to run blocking Firebase operations?

**For example:**

I know `setValue()` does not return a boolean, I'm asking if there is a similar API that does something like the below code

```
// we are in a background thread

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

boolean success = ref.child("user").child("name").setValue("Arthur");

// code is blocked until operation completes

Log.d("MY_TAG", "successfull operation:" + success);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FirebaseDatabase API does not include a blocking form of [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object)).  You can use the returned [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) to add blocking in your own code in a worker (non-Main) thread:

```
    boolean success = false;
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Task task = ref.child("user").child("name").setValue("Arthur");

    try {
        Tasks.await(task);
        success = task.isSuccessful();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("MY_TAG", "successfull operation:" + success);
```

A [Semaphore](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) can be used for a blocking read.  Because the listener callbacks run on the Main thread, this code can only run on another thread.  If run on the Main thread, it deadlocks.

```
    final Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    ref.child("user").child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.i("MY_TAG", "Name=" + name);
            sem.release();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("MY_TAG", "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            sem.release();
        }
    });

    try {
        sem.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.w("MY_TAG", "Interrupted");
    }
```

You can also use a `Task` for a blocking read (off the Main thread):

```
    final TaskCompletionSource<DataSnapshot> taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
    final Task<DataSnapshot> task = taskSource.getTask();

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    ref.child("user").child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            taskSource.setResult(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            taskSource.setException(databaseError.toException());
        }
    });

    try {
        Tasks.await(task);

        String name = task.getResult().getValue(String.class);
        Log.i("MY_TAG", "Name=" + name);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Log.e("MY_TAG", "Read failed: " + task.getException().getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.w("MY_TAG", "Read interrupted");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks qbix! This seems to do the trick for setValue(). Is there a way to do the same with "read" operations? (i.e. replacing DatabaseReference's addListenerForSingleValueEvent() with a Task on which I can wait?